# ValueProvider not called for property not in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm not having any luck getting a custom value provider to be called for a property on my view model. I'm trying to encapsulate some of the standard request data, such as UserHostAddress into my view model, using a custom value provider.

For example, my view model looks like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I want my custom value provider to populate the IPAddress property automatically. Unfortunately, GetValue is never called for that property. This seems strange, as I thought the DefaultModelBinder would iterate over the model's properties and check the value providers for a value.

Comment: Did you register your custom value provider factory?

Comment: I think I have the same problem. `GetValue` *only* seems to get called for the to-be-populated-property when my request includes any other property (e.g. in your case: if `name` would get passed, either as a route parameter or via the query string), but not when the request does not contain any parameters. In that case, my controller just receives `null` for `MyViewModel`. `GetValue` gets called with the name of the parameter and an empty string, but not for the to-be-populated property (`IPAddress` in your example).

Have you found the reason and perhaps a solution?

Comment: For me I had to add `IUriValueProviderFactory` to my `ValueProviderFactory` before it was considered by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a custom value provider:

```
public class MyValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        if (key.EndsWith("Name"))
        {
            var value = "john";
            return new ValueProviderResult(value, value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (key.EndsWith("IPAddress"))
        {
            var value = "127.0.0.1";
            return new ValueProviderResult(value, value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and a corresponding factory:

```
public class MyValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        return new MyValueProvider();
    }
}
```

that will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyValueProviderFactory());
```

and now you could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.IPAddress)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Your custom value provider will be used by the default model binder.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I have a custom value provider, but the GetValue method of it wasn't called. I found the answer and will update the question.